# How to shorten a column data of a table and add dots after a specific limit using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="title"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consecteconsLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consecteconsLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consecteconsLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now take class **title** i want to trim the data of **title** class and add (...) after a specific length using javascript there can be multiple `<td>`
Help me

Comment: you want trim all td's or only the td's with class title?

Comment: @MaikLowrey only the class **title**, i wrote some code which only effect when there is only i title

Answer (score 1):

```
const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
const titleLength = 15;
titles.forEach(el => {
  el.innerText = `${el.innerText.substring(0, titleLength)}...`;
})
```

explanation: substring.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the columns by class and substring the data and set it back.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td.title')
const length = 10;
tds.forEach((e) => {
  e.innerText = e.innerText.substring(0, length) + '...';
})
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="title"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consecteconsLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consecteconsLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consecteconsLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectecons sit amet consectecons</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
</tr>
</table>
```